# Javascript for checkbox to copy billing text boxes over to shipping text boxes

Tags: javascript, forms, textbox

So far, I have been trying to find a good way of taking Billing information in text boxes and copying the information over to Shipping information text boxes when a user checks the checkbox stating that their billing info is the same as their shipping info.

I have this code so far:

```
    function InputInformation(n) {   
        if(n.checked === false) { return; }
        document.subscribe.billingfname.value = document.subscribe.shippingfname.value;
        document.subscribe.billinglname.value = document.subscribe.shippinglname.value;
        document.subscribe.billingaddress.value = document.subscribe.shippingaddress.value;
        document.subscribe.billingcity.value = document.subscribe.shippingcity.value;
        document.subscribe.billingstate.value = document.subscribe.shippingstate.value;
        document.subscribe.billingzip.value = document.subscribe.shippingzip.value;
        document.subscribe.billingphone.value = document.subscribe.shippingphone.value;
        }
          return InputInformation;
```

And I cannot get it work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be great!

The javascript goes along to this form:

```
<form class="wrap" name="subscribe">
            <tr class="left-container">
            <h2>Billing Information:</h2>
            <td>
                <span class="labels">First name: </span>
            <input type="text" name="billingfname">
            </td>
                <br>
                <td>
            <span class="labels"> Last name: </span>
            <input type="text" name="billinglname">
            </td>
                <br>
                <td>
            <span class="labels">Address: </span>
            <input type="text" name="billingaddress" style="width: 200px">
           </td>
                <br>
                <td>
            <span class="labels">City: </span>
            <input type="text" name="billingcity">
            </td>
                <br>
                <td>
            <span class="labels">State: </span>
            <input type="text" name="billingstate">
            </td>
                <br>
                <td>
            <span class="labels">Zip Code: </span>
            <input type="text" name="billingzip" style="width: 80px">
            </td>
                <br>
                <td>
            <span class="labels">Telephone </span>
            <input type="text" name="billingphone" style="width: 80px">
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="right-container">
            <h2>Shipping Information:</h2>
                <td>
                <input class="shipping" type="checkbox" onclick="InputInformation(this)">Check if Shipping is the same as Billing
                </td>
                <br>
                <td>
            <span class="labels">First name: </span>
            <input type="text" name="shippingfname">
            </td>
                <br>
                <td>
            <span class="labels"> Last name: </span>
            <input type="text" name="shippinglname">
            </td>
                <br>
                <td>
            <span class="labels">Address: </span>
            <input type="text" name="shippingaddress" style="width: 200px">
             </td>
                <br>
                <td>
            <span class="labels">City: </span>
            <input type="text" name="shippingcity">
            </td>
                <br>
                <td>
            <span class="labels">State: </span>
            <input type="text" name="shippingstate">
           </td>
                <br>
                <td>
            <span class="labels">Zip Code: </span>
            <input type="text" name="shippingzip" style="width: 80px">
            </td>
                <br>
                <td>
            <span class="labels">Telephone </span>
            <input type="text" name="shippingphone" style="width: 80px">
                    </td>
            </tr>
</form>
```

Comment: whats with the return InputInformation; where does that come from?

Comment: You seem to have the `return` statement outside of the function definition. Is that intentional or a mistake?

Comment: sorry, yes that was a mistake, but it still isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are trying to copy the shipping to the billing in your code snippet should be other way round.

Check the snippet below.

```js
function InputInformation(n) {   
  if(n.checked === false) { alert('sdf');return false; }
  document.subscribe.shippingfname.value = document.subscribe.billingfname.value;
  document.subscribe.shippinglname.value = document.subscribe.billinglname.value;
  document.subscribe.shippingaddress.value = document.subscribe.billingaddress.value;
  document.subscribe.shippingcity.value = document.subscribe.billingcity.value;
  document.subscribe.shippingstate.value = document.subscribe.billingstate.value;
  document.subscribe.shippingzip.value = document.subscribe.billingzip.value;
  document.subscribe.shippingphone.value = document.subscribe.billingphone.value;
}
```

```html
<form class="wrap" name="subscribe">
  <tr class="left-container">
    <h2>Billing Information:</h2>
    <td>
      <span class="labels">First name: </span>
      <input type="text" name="billingfname">
    </td>
    <br>
    <td>
      <span class="labels"> Last name: </span>
      <input type="text" name="billinglname">
    </td>
    <br>
    <td>
      <span class="labels">Address: </span>
      <input type="text" name="billingaddress" style="width: 200px">
    </td>
    <br>
    <td>
      <span class="labels">City: </span>
      <input type="text" name="billingcity">
    </td>
    <br>
    <td>
      <span class="labels">State: </span>
      <input type="text" name="billingstate">
    </td>
    <br>
    <td>
      <span class="labels">Zip Code: </span>
      <input type="text" name="billingzip" style="width: 80px">
    </td>
    <br>
    <td>
      <span class="labels">Telephone </span>
      <input type="text" name="billingphone" style="width: 80px">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="right-container">
    <h2>Shipping Information:</h2>
    <td>
      <input class="shipping" type="checkbox" onchange="InputInformation(this)">Check if Shipping is the same as Billing
    </td>
    <br>
    <td>
      <span class="labels">First name: </span>
      <input type="text" name="shippingfname">
    </td>
    <br>
    <td>
      <span class="labels"> Last name: </span>
      <input type="text" name="shippinglname">
    </td>
    <br>
    <td>
      <span class="labels">Address: </span>
      <input type="text" name="shippingaddress" style="width: 200px">
    </td>
    <br>
    <td>
      <span class="labels">City: </span>
      <input type="text" name="shippingcity">
    </td>
    <br>
    <td>
      <span class="labels">State: </span>
      <input type="text" name="shippingstate">
    </td>
    <br>
    <td>
      <span class="labels">Zip Code: </span>
      <input type="text" name="shippingzip" style="width: 80px">
    </td>
    <br>
    <td>
      <span class="labels">Telephone </span>
      <input type="text" name="shippingphone" style="width: 80px">
    </td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't realize I had them switched. But for some reason, after fixing the code, it still won't work in my code. It works when I run your code on here, but not in my text editor. Any suggestions?